# The sum of two string output

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, sum

How can I sum the two string scores in the output and type them in a single line without repeating the same domain?

My code:

```
score_dict = {"redapple": "30",
              "greenapple": "50",
              "red": "5"}

results = []
with open("domain.txt", 'r') as g:
    for domain in g.readlines():
        hit = None
        for substring, score in score_dict.items():
            for hit in score_dict:
                if substring in domain:
                    if domain == domain:
                        hit = True
                        results.append({'domain': domain.strip(), 'substring': substring, 'score': score})
                        break
            if not hit:
                results.append({'domain': domain.strip(), 'substring': substring, 'score': 0})

with open("score_result.txt", "w") as file:
    for item in results:
        file.write("%s\n" % item)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{'domain': 'redgreenapple.com', 'substring': 'red', 'score': '5'}
{'domain': 'redgreenapple.com', 'substring': 'greenapple', 'score': '50'}
```

That's what I want `redgreenapple.com` the domain can print the `total score` in a `single line` `without repeating` it.

**The output I want:**

```
{'domain': 'redgreenapple.com', 'substring': 'red, greenapple', 'score': '55'}
```

**OR:**

```
{'domain': 'redgreenapple.com', 'substring': 'red, 'substring': 'greenapple, 'score': '55'}
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @MYousefi Sorry. I forgot, I added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do what you need. Instead of using a list I'm using a dictionary to keep the results for each domain. To add the scores you just need to convert to numbers and back to string after `sum`. I'm also keeping the substrings in a list and then joining them at the end.

```
score_dict = {"redapple": "30",
              "greenapple": "50",
              "red": "5"}

results = dict()
with open("domain.txt", 'r') as g:
    for domain in g.readlines():
        domain = domain.strip()
        if domain not in results:
            results[domain] = {'domain': domain, 'substring': [], 'score': 0}
        for substring, score in score_dict.items():
            if substring in domain:
                results[domain]['substring'].append(substring)
                results[domain]['score'] += int(score)
        results[domain]['substring'] = ', '.join(results[domain]['substring'])
        results[domain]['score'] = str(results[domain]['score'])
```

Check substring to find if it matched anything.

```
with open("score_result.txt", "w") as file:
    for domain in results:
        if results[domain]['substring']:  # If there are no matches it will be ''
            file.write("%s\n" % results[domain])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic way to combine a list of dictionaries based on a key and put them into another list. You can then write `final_results` into a file.

```py
results = [{'domain': 'redgreenapple.com', 'substring': 'red', 'score': '5'},{'domain': 'redgreenapple.com', 'substring': 'greenapple', 'score': '50'}]

unique_domains = set(x['domain'] for x in results)
final_results = []
for domain in unique_domains:
    item = {"domain": domain, "substring": "", "score": "0"}
    for x in results:
        if x['domain'] == domain:
            item["substring"] = item['substring'] + ", " + x['substring']
            item["score"] = str(int(item["score"]) + int(x["score"]))
    # remove extra comma in front
    item["substring"] = item["substring"][2:]
    final_results.append(item)

[{'domain': 'redgreenapple.com', 'substring': 'red, greenapple', 'score': '55'}]
```